# Surfaces as product of curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be two smooth curves of genus $g\geq 1$. When we consider the surface $S=C_1\times C_2$ what kind of surface do we get in the sense of Enriques--Kodaira classification of surfaces?

Comment: http://touch-geometry.karazin.ua/list

Answer (score 6):

a) If  both curves have genus $g(C_i)=1$, the surface $S=C_1\times C_2$ has Kodaira dimension $\kappa(S)=0$ and $S$ is an abelian surface.

b) If $g(C_1)=1$ and $g(C_2)\gt 1$, the surface $S=C_1\times C_2$ has Kodaira dimension $\kappa(S)=1$ and $S$ is an elliptic surface.

c) If both curves have genus $g(C_i)\geq 2$, the surface $S=C_1\times C_2$ has Kodaira dimension $\kappa(S)=2$ and $S$ is a surface of general type.

**Edit**
For smooth projective varieties $V,W$ we have the extremely pleasant formula for Kodaira dimensions $$    \kappa (V\times W)= \kappa (V) +\kappa(W)     $$ which immediately yields the above result.

Comment: Ok. So the surface $S$ is in general not minimal and containes $-1$ curves, right?

Comment: Dear user109227, I have no idea how you come to that conclusion.